# InDesign: Table of Contents with differently coloured numbering

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles, formatting, table-of-contents

I want to generate a TOC whose numbers are a different colour form the actual text. Here an example made in Photoshop:

[image: Table of content with coloured numbers]

As you can see the leading numbering is in blue, but the text itself is in black.

---

I sadly have no idea how to recreate this in InDesign. When I make a table of contents I can choose a Paragraph style for the text, but no character style for the numbering (at least I cannot find it). Also when I add numbering in my paragraph style, I simply have 2 numberings ... one in the desired colour and one in black (coming from the TOC). This obviously is not what I desire.

Comment: May I ask if the numbers is coming from the original source? For example the "1." before "Introduction" how are you creating that?

Comment: @Mamoon yes, the headings in the document themselves are numbered: https://imgur.com/a/h9ziS

Comment: Cool. are these automated numberings created via Paragraph Styles or how did you create them?

Comment: @Mamoon yes, they are automatically generated using the numbering option https://imgur.com/a/NkFXK

Comment: Have you noticed the "Style:" field in the middle of the TOC window? This allows you to set a Paragraph style for each Included item. Then to color each number differently you need to assign a character style to the Numbering under the paragraph style that you are intending to use. Sorry it may sound crowded but I hop you understand. If not then I can elaborate.

Comment: Do you mean these: https://imgur.com/a/t1whg

Because I already defined a style different from the one I used for the headings, whithout numbering: https://imgur.com/a/kCoY4

If I add numbering here, this is the result:
https://imgur.com/a/OaIxG

which .... umhh ... yeah xD

Comment: Ahhh, that has not been accounted for! So that is a call for "Nested Styles" in the Paragraph Style you applied for the TOC! Under the Paragraph styles There is "Drop Caps and Nested Styles" Under nested styles select the Character Style you want the number to be and select (through // 1 // . ) https://imgur.com/a/m9BwM

For the numbers 2.1.  (select through // 2 // . )

Comment: Ah, cool. Thx. Just another question: What if my numbering ever reaches 10 and above? Then I would have different amounts of characters to style for the headings. Is there a way to make a rule like: Apply character style to all characters before ^t ?

Comment: Yes exactly! Chose /Tab Characters/ from the drop down menu. That means it will apply the Character style to every character until it reaches the first tab. https://imgur.com/a/GZyJK

Comment: awesome! Could you post that as an answer so I can set the question to solved? :)

Comment: Yes will do it! Happy that it worked out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you need to use Nested Styles for the Paragraph Style assigned under TOC.

It should use something like this.

[image]

This will apply a Character Style to Characters from the beginning of the Paragraph and stops when it reaches the first Tab, which in this case is the one right after your List Numbering.

Good luck!

Comment: Anytime! Good luck. Will be nice to show us the final designs!!!